# JavaScript - função que retona um objeto

Tags: javascript, funções, objetos

Estou tentando passar um desafio e estou tendo dificuldades para passar pelos seguintes tópicos:

1. Escreva uma função chamada `createCars` que irá receber três argumentos: *nome, estrelas e marca*. Esta função deve retornar um objeto. O objeto que retorna deve ter propriedades que também são chamadas de *nome, ano e marca.* Os valores atribuídos a estas propriedades devem ser os valores que são passados para a função. Além disso, o objeto que `createCars` retorna deve ter dois métodos:

   `hasMorestrelasThan` - uma função que aceita um objeto "nome" como parâmetro e retorna true se o nome tem mais "estrelas" do que aquele que é passado para ele como um argumento, e falso caso contrário.

   `sayMarca` - uma função que regista o valor da propriedade  "marca" do objeto "nome" para o console.

O que eu tenho para esta primeira etapa:

```
function createCar(nome, estrelas, marca) {

    myObject.nome = "nome";

    myObject.estrelas = "estrelas";

    myObject.marca= "marca";

    retun Object

}
```

Eu sou completamente iniciante e estou tentando aprender sozinha. Se alguem puder ajudar, ficarei eternamente grata!

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Dê uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para mais informações de como funciona o site. Procure informar qual a dificuldade específica, o erro que ocorre, onde ocorre, etc. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,
Vamos partir do início e criar seu objeto de maneira correta. Veja:

```js
function createCar(nome, estrelas, marca) {
    myObject = {}; // cria o objeto myObject
    retun myObject;
}
```

Agora vamos as suas adaptações e lógicas. Observe:

```js
function createCar(nome, estrelas, marca, ano) {
    myObject = {};

    myObject.nome = nome;
    myObject.estrelas = estrelas;
    myObject.marca= marca;
    myObject.ano = ano;

    myObject.hasMorestrelasThan = function (stars){
        if(this.estrelas < stars){ // pega estrelas do objeto myObject e compara com a starts (passada para a função)
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    };

    myObject.sayMarca = function (){
        console.log(this.marca); // acessa a marca do objeto myObject
    }

    retun myObject;
}
```

Pelo que eu entendi da sua dúvida era mais ou menos isso que você queria. Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Comment: Lucas, MUITO obrigada! Você foi o herói do meu dia!

Comment: Só uma coisa: não entendi porque você compara com stars. Neste caso, eu poderia comparar com qualquer outra propriedade? Eu realmente estou confusa com isso.

Comment: Olá, neste caso você está comparando o stars (enviado como parâmetro da função myObject.hasMorestrelasThan) com o myObject.estrelas (enviado como parâmetro da função  createCar). Se deseja comparar dois elementos quaisquer, você pode adicionar um parâmetro stars2 na função, por exemplo. E modificar o if para `if(stars > stars2)`... e daí vai

Comment: Entendi, Lucas! Muito obrigada! Vou tentar resolver o desafio todo! :)